# Use an object even though `__init__()` raises an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm in a situation where some meager important parts of a classes `__init__` method could raise an exception. In that case I want to display an error message but carry on using the instance.

A very basic example:

```
class something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        do_something_important()
        raise IrrelevantException()

    def do_something_useful(self):
        pass

try:
    that_thing = something()
except IrrelevantException:
    print("Something less important failed.")

that_thing.do_something_useful()
```

However, the last line does not work, because `that_thing` is not defined. Strange thing is, I could swear I've done things like this before and it worked fine. I even thougt about ways to keep people from using such an unfinished instance, because I found out it gets created even in case of errors. Now I wanted to use that and it does not work. Hmmm...?!?

PS: `something` was written by myself, so I'm in control of everything.

Comment: The right-hand side of an assignment has to be *successfully evaluated* before it can actually get assigned, so it shouldn't be surprising that `that_thing` isn't defined. Even though the object was *created* (prior to being *initialised*), you don't have a reference to it if the assignment fails, so it will get garbage collected. If you *did* keep a reference somewhere, e.g. via a class or metaclass, then you *could* still call methods on it.

Comment: Raising an exception in a constructor means that the object _cannot_ be constructed, so you won’t be able to use it. If there’s a situation in which things that happen inside of the constructor may fail but the object would still be _constructed_, then that stuff should not be part of the constructor.

Comment: @poke That's a _bit_ misleading. `__new__` is the constructor; `__init__` is the initializer. And that difference is relevant here, even if not that often, because you could well have a `__new__` that returns a valid object, then an `__init__` that does "irrelevant stuff", and you could solve that by, e.g., having the `__init__` method or a metaclass or whatever stash the `self` somewhere, but that wouldn't work inside a constructor.

Comment: Given the PS, this is a trivial question: Just print an error instead of raising an exception, and then the whole problem with how to handle that exception elsewhere doesn't arise in the first place.

Comment: Even though I asked this question, I would consider it bad style now. If it would work this way, it would be an ugly glitch, because, as @jonrsharpe said, the right-hand side of an assignment has to be successfully evaluated before it can actually get assigned. Code that might fail without rendering the instance unusable should not be part of the `__init__` method, but placed in a separate "load" method that can be called on the instance after initialization is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment:

> PS: something was written by myself, so I'm in control of everything.

Well, then the answer is obvious: just remove that `raise IrrelevantException()`

Of course your real code probably doesn't have `raise IrrelevantException`, but instead a call to some `dangerous_function()` that *might* raise. But that's fine; you can handle the exception the same way you do anywhere else; the fact that you're inside an `__init__` method makes no difference:

```
class something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        do_something_important()
        try:
            do_something_dangerous()
        except IrrelevantException as e:
            print(f'do_something_dangerous raised {e!r}')
        do_other_stuff_if_you_have_any()
```

That's all there is to it. There's no reason your `__init__` should be raising an exception, and therefore the question of how to handle that exception never arises in the first place.

---

If you can't modify `something`, but can subclass it, then you don't need anything fancy:

```
class IrrelevantException(Exception):
    pass

def do_something_important():
    pass

class something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        do_something_important()
        raise IrrelevantException()

    def do_something_useful(self):
        pass

class betterthing(something):
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            super().__init__() # use 2.x style if you're on 2.x of course
        except IrrelevantException:
            pass # or log it, or whatever
        # You can even do extra stuff after the exception

that_thing = betterthing()
that_thing.do_something_useful()
```

Now `do_something_important` got called, and a `something` instance got returns that I was able to save and call `do_something_useful` on, and so on. Exactly what you were looking for.

---

You could of course hide `something` behind `betterthing` with some clever renaming tricks:

```
_something = something
class something(_something):
    # same code as above
```

… or just monkeypatch `something.__init__` with a wrapper function instead of wrapping the class:

```
_init = something.__init__
def __init__(self):
    try:
        _init(self)
    except IrrelevantException:
        pass
something.__init__ = __init__
```

But, unless there's a good reason that you can't be explicit about the fact that you're adding a wrapper it, it's probably better to be explicit.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by calling `object.__new__()` to create the object. Then after that call `__init__()` to create the object.

This will execute all of the code possible.

```
class IrrelevantException(Exception):
    """This is not important, keep executing."""
    pass

class something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Doing important stuff.")
        raise IrrelevantException()

    def do_something_useful(self):
       print("Now this is useful.")

that_thing = object.__new__(something) # Create the object, does not call __init__
try:
    that_thing.__init__() # Now run __init__
except IrrelevantException:
    print("Something less important failed.")

that_thing.do_something_useful() # And everything that __init__ could do is done.
```

---

EDIT, as @abarnert pointed out. This code does presume that `__init__()` is defined, but `__new__()` is not.

Now if it can be assumed that `__new__()` will not error, it can replace `object.__new__()` in the code.

However, if there is an error in `object.__new__()`, there is no way to both create the instance, and have the actions in `__new__()` applied to it.

This is because `__new__()` returns the instance, versus `__init__()` which manipulates the instance. (When you call `something()`, the default `__new__()` function actually calls `__init__()` and then quietly returns the instance.)

So the most robust version of this code would be:

```
class IrrelevantException(Exception):
    """This is not important, keep executing."""
    pass

class something(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Doing important stuff.")
        raise IrrelevantException()

    def do_something_useful(self):
       print("Now this is useful.")

try:
    that_thing = something.__new__(something) # Create the object, does not call __init__
except IrrelevantException:
    # Well, just create the object without calling cls.__new__()
    that_thing = object.__new__(something)
try:
    that_thing.__init__() # Now run __init__
except IrrelevantException:
    print("Something less important failed.")

that_thing.do_something_useful()
```

So, meanwhile both of these answer the question, this latter one should also help in the (admittedly rare) case where `__new__()` has an error, but this does not stop `do_something_useful()` from working.

Comment: This assumes that `something` (and any other superclasses between it and `object`) doesn't override `__new__`. Which is true for the OP's example, but it might not be true for their real code, so it might be worth mentioning the assumption in the answer.

Comment: In fact I ended up with something like this, but instead of working around all the instance creation "magic" by calling all the double underscore methods from outside, I just settled for the clean way of doing it, by moving the somewhat optional code to a separate method. So it's just: `that_thing = something(); try: that_thing.init_more(); except IrrelevantException: print("Something less important failed.")`

Answer (score 2):

You can't have both an exception raised and a value returned (without getting hacky).  If this is all code you control, then may I suggest this pattern:

```
class something(object):
   Exception = None
   def __init__(self):
      ...
      if BadStuff:
         self.Exception = IrrelevantException()
      ...

that_thing = something()
if that_thing.Exception:
   print(that_thing.Exception)

# carry on
```

Note, if you are just looking for a message, then don't bother creating an `Exception` object, but rather just set an error code/message on self, and check for it later.

Comment: You should only call `__init__` if `isinstance(self, something)`

Comment: The second version won't help anything. If `something.__new__` returns an instance of `something` (or a subclass thereof), its `__init__` method will automatically get called. Even if you've already called it once. So now you'll just be doing all the init code twice (which might cause new problems) and then failing in the same way as the original code.

Comment: Calling `type.__new__` returns a new `type` object instead of a new `something` instance. I'm pretty sure you'll get an exception from calling it with the wrong arguments (it expects a name, sequence of bases, and namespace mapping). If not, what you'll get back is a new _class_, which (assuming `something.__init__` doesn't just `TypeError` it), is not going to support any of the methods of `something` will instead of the methods of classes (like `__call__` to construct a new instance), will have class attributes where you expected object attributes, etc.

Comment: i like this but why not try/catch everything in the init past the “bare minimum/important”?  assign self.exception = None at start, then populate in the catch?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't have control over the "something" class, so in that case you can call the method directly, assuming that there are no elements in the class that are needed.  You're passing self=None though, so it won't be able to have any access to the class's variables.

```
    class IrrelevantException(Exception):
        x = "i don't matter"

    class something(object):
        def __init__(self):
            raise IrrelevantException()

        def do_something_useful(self):
            print('hi')

    #this will fail
    try:
        that_thing = something()
    except IrrelevantException:
        print("Something less important failed.")

    #this will run
    something.do_something_useful(None)
```

Alternatively you can use inheritance:

```
    class mega_something(something):
        def __init__(self):
            print("its alive!")


    that_other_thing = mega_something()
    that_other_thing.do_something_useful()
```

The mega_something class won't run its parent constructor unless called.

Comment: But in that case there's no point even *trying* to create the instance, since you don't actually need it "do something useful".

Comment: Also, your inheritance solution doesn't really solve anything—it prevents _all_ of the `__init__` code from being called, including the `do_something_important`, which is presumably important.